Can foreigners use Swedish app-driven self service stores?
In Sweden I found multiple self-service stores that needed a smartphone to enter.
According to the instructions, customers would have to install an app and then identify using Bank ID. One such store was in a remote location along a main road in Kåbdalis / Goabddális (around 100 inhabitants), 60 km south of Jokkmokk / Jåhkåmåhkke and 95 km north of Arvidsjaur / Árviesjávrrie.  Another was in central Gällivare / Váhtjer (around 11k inhabitants).
Is it possible for foreign visitors to use such stores?  I've seen self-service stores in Germany and Norway, but they did not require any smartphone to enter and it is no problem for me to use those stores.  I suppose I could wait for another customer and tag along (could be a while, considering the rural location), but even then I don't know if I would be able to scan groceries and pay.

Are these out of the way locations or middle of town?

@Willeke I've seen both — one in central Gällivare / Váhtjer (around 11k inhabitants), one in the rural village of Kåbdalis / Goabddális (around 100 inhabitants).

Related question but a different location so no duplicate: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/191354/is-it-possible-for-non-residents-to-access-app-based-stores-in-dubai

FWIW, many Norwegian self-service stores require that you identify using your Vipps account, a proprietary Norwegian payment system, also only available to residents of Norway. Unfortunately, 'Vipps payment only' is also a phenomenon, which is spreading in Norway and making it complicated for tourists, not only in self-service stores, but also for private accomodation, in smaller shops, at farmer's markets etc.

@Tor-EinarJarnbjo Well, yes, at a market in Umeå (Sweden) I was unable to buy something at one stand because they took only Swish, which afaik is the same as Vipps but in Sweden.  But at least in the self-service store in Tufsingdalen in May 2024 I was able to enter (but I had to scan my receipt to leave, which was hard as I had not found what I needed and bought nothing — but that applies equally to locals so is not a travel problem as such).  I admit that my sampling size is small (one self-service store in Norway I could enter, two in Sweden I could not enter).

A colleague of mine has a summer cabin close to a store like this in a location with many foreign visitors who run in to this problem. According to him, a representative for the store had told them that it was okay to let other customers in and it is possible to pay without BankID. Just an anecdote, YMMV.

Generally speaking, the situation with these things is a lot worse in Sweden than it is in Norway. In Norway you can in fact mostly get by with plain cash, or at least credit card (e.g.  automated fuel stations). In Sweden... well actually most shops still accept cash too although almost nobody uses it, but many shops refuse. Most take credit card, but there really is a lot of stuff that can only be done with a smartphone app.

@leftaroundabout As a Swede and a privacy nerd I've managed so far without Swish but I don't know how long until I run into something that requires it.

Those that require BankID can't be used by visitors since a bank account is needed to get BankID. If another customer lets you in they likely breach their contract with the store.
But there are stores with other options than BankID, for example: Never Closed.

Your link shows it still needs "BankID, Finskt BankID, Dansk Mit ID, Norskt BankID eller Smart-ID.".  Is Smart-ID available to foreign visitors?

Looks like stores in the "never closed" chain can be used by visitors from Nordic/Baltic countries but not others?

The Neverclosed FAQ says you can use a SMS(text) code to get in, sadly I don't know the details

Yeah, the Neverclosed FAQ says (via Google Translate) "you can  log in using an SMS code . Additional information about how to proceed, you can find on the entrance door of the store". Presumably it uses your phone to validate your identity, but that doesn't mean it accepts all phones on all networks worldwide.

@StuartF Hmm.  In other contexts, I've found that SMS codes might work only with domestic SIMs, but a well-prepared foreign visitor could get one of those, so that could potentially work.
