Is it possible for non-residents to access app-based stores in Dubai?
With the rise of technology, app-based stores are becoming more common in places like Dubai. But is it easy for non-residents to access and use these services? Many tourists and expats might find the convenience appealing, but are there any restrictions or challenges they face when trying to shop at these stores? Have you had any experience with app-based shopping in Dubai as a non-resident? What was your experience like?

Related question, different location so no duplicate: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/191350/can-foreigners-use-swedish-app-driven-self-service-stores

Any particular store you're interested in? This question is rather vague - are you interested in challenges such as not being admitted or not being able to pay, or would stuff like signage in Arabic or harsh lighting and intrusive security be relevant? The only store I can find with this is Carrefour+, with access via the Carrefour app which is apparently internationally available, without any mention of any restrictions.

At least in Bahrain, all you need is a local mobile number.
